# Who is snap_daemon & snapd-range-524288-root and Ubuntu.com?

Tags: security, users, hacking, ubuntu-pro

Snap_daemon & snapd-range-524288-root hacked into my computer as users, and messed it up not giving me access to change multiple programs to fix them. I deleted them as users along with their information, yet still some functions like "about this computer" and "system settings" would not work. As I tried to fix it, my machine in terminal suggest I purchase Ubuntu Pro. At first I thought, well, that it innocent enough and signed up. Then I thought about all the people who have sacrificed to make this a free program clear of corporate interest and deleted my subscription. I took all data off my computer in flash drives and reloaded Ubuntu on my computer. My question is who is running Ubuntu Pro, and who is Snap_daemon & snapd-range-524288-root?

Comment: Often, packages create their own userids (and groups) to aid in "process separation". They're not necessarily signs of a hack. Did you investigate the userids? What were the UIDs, GIDs, User name, home directory, command interpreter? Did you save a copy of `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`

Comment: "*[W]ho is running Ubuntu Pro[?]*" See https://ubuntu.com/pro, look near the bottom of the page. It is not nefarious. It also makes no promises to fix any of the problems you have described so far.

Answer (score 1):

Users created with `useradd` have a UID of 1000–60000 and can be listed with the following command:

```
awk -F: '$3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {print $1}' /etc/passwd
```

The results of running this command on your computer will be similar to this output which is similar to what I got on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop which has Ubuntu Pro enabled.

```
maryt
snapd-range-524288-root
snap_daemon
```

I have assumed for the purpose of showing this example that you are the only user on your computer, and that your user name is *maryt*. These results are perfectly normal including the 6-digit number 524288 in `snapd-range-524288-root`, and there is nothing wrong with Ubuntu on your computer.

Comment: Is this on server only? Cannot see this on a regular Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.

Comment: This output is not just for servers. I got the same results on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop which has Ubuntu Pro enabled.